# One column table, displays random integers, all in one loop

Tags: javascript, loops, random, numbers, html-table

I need to write a program that will generate a table and display a randomly generated number within the cell, the program should iterate 10 times, any help? This is what I have so far

```
<Script>    
function generate() {   
var counter = 0;    
document.write('<table><tr>');      
    if(counter<10)  {           
    document.write('<td>');             
    var tblcell = document.getElementById('tblcell2');
    var cellnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    tblcell.innerHTML = cellnum;
    document.write('</td>');
    counter++;      
    }       
document.write('</tr></table>');
}   
</Script>     

<div class='format'> 
<form>
<input type='button' onClick = 'generate()' value='Generate Colors'/>                   
</form> 
</div> 
<span id='tblcell2'></span>
```

Comment: don´t use document.write, use document.createElement

Comment: If you want to iterate don't use if(counter<10) but while(counter<10)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I applied the changes and still no table is generated onClick, any other ideas?